# Does this condition imply convergence of $\sum_k x_k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers (in principle, they could be complex numbers, but I don't think this makes much of a difference for this problem).

Suppose the sequence $x_n$ satisfies the following condition (which comes from the problem I'm investigating):
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty {\left|\sum_{i = k}^{n+k} x_i \right|^2} < \infty $$

Does this necessarily imply that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ converges?

*Comments*:
 
This would clearly be true if the $x_n$ were nonnegative real numbers.

Also, even in the case with arbitrary real numbers, it is clear that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ cannot converge to infinity. However, it could be possible that the series goes "up and down" while holding the sup condition true.